# how can I use parameters in navigate (react-router)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I tried to pass params to a component when I used the `navigate` function.

I tried many ways none worked.

this is the route (in the App.js):

```
<Route path='/Lessons' element={<LessonsList />} />
```

this is the component:

```js
function LessonsList({ lessonsList }) {
  ...
}

export...
```

the code on another page - where I try to navigate with params:

```js
const navigate = useNavigate();
const lessonslist = [{ name: "lesson1", id: "11" }];
navigate('/Lessons', lessonslist);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pass params like this when you use react-router-dom v6.

```
const lessonslist = [{ name: "lesson1", id: "11" }];
navigate('/Lessons',{state:{ lessonslist }});
```

And you can get the lessonslist in LessonsList component like this.

```
const { state: { lessonslist } = {} } = useLocation();
```

Comment: it doesn't work.
I wanna pass list
and how can I use the params in the component?

Comment: You can get the params like this.
const { state: { name, id } = {} } = useLocation();

Comment: @Loui And you need to remove lessonsList from props of LessonsList component.

Comment: @Loui Just follow the steps/implementation in the duplicate target, it explains all this.